# Django using a Query in a Query does not work

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

so I have this model :

```
class Student(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=30,default="",blank=True)
    tel=models.CharField(max_length=50,default="",blank=True)
    e_mail=models.CharField(max_length=50,default="",blank=True)
    social_media=models.CharField(max_length=50,default="",blank=True)
    social_media2=models.CharField(max_length=50,default="",blank=True)
    social_media3=models.CharField(max_length=50,default="",blank=True)
    street=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    postal=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    graduation_uni=models.DateField(null=True,default=None,blank=True)
    graduation_ikomt=models.DateField(null=True,default=None,blank=True)
    certificate_no=models.CharField(max_length=50,default="",blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + " - " +self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

class Course(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
course=models.CharField(max_length=50)
description=models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,default=None,blank=True)
start_date=models.DateField(null=True,default=None,blank=True)
end_date=models.DateField(null=True,default=None,blank=True)


def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id) + " - " +self.course + " | " + self.start_date.strftime("%d.%m.%y") + " - " + self.end_date.strftime("%d.%m.%y")

class StudentInCourse(models.Model):
    StudentId = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    CourseId = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(Student.objects.get(id=self.StudentId.id)) + " in " + str(Course.objects.get(id=self.CourseId.id))
```

And I'd like to Display only the Students in a specific course using Queries like this (in my views.py):

```
students_in_course=StudentInCourse.objects.filter(CourseId=id)
 latest_student_list = Student.objects.filter(id__in=students_in_course)
```

Sadly, I only get an empty result. Any Ideas what I'm doing wrong? I thought with the Primary/Foreign Key relation the Filter should just work this way?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to filter in such way that you retrieve `Student`s that "*happen*" to have the same primary key as the primary key of a `StudentInCourse` object, this does not make much sense.

You can filter with:

```
latest_student_list = Student.objects.filter(studentincourse__CourseId=id)
```

or if you want to work with two `QuerySet`s (which looks less elegant), you can work with:

```
students_in_course=StudentInCourse.objects.filter(CourseId=id).values('StudentId')
latest_student_list = Student.objects.filter(id__in=students_in_course)
```

---

> **Note**: Normally one does not add a suffix `Id` to a `ForeignKey` field, since Django
> will automatically add a "twin" field with an `_id` suffix. Therefore it should
> be `course`, instead of <s>`CourseId`</s>.